# Not being able to use Math.random properly

Tags: javascript, random

I've been working on a little bacteria simulator where the directions the bacteria take is "random", but it's creating a pattern where all bacteria go down the screen, why is this? what am I doing wrong?

**My code:**

```js
var sandbox = "#main";
spawn(1);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(sandbox).animate({
    "height": $(sandbox).height()
  }, 500, function() {
    step();
  });
}

function spawn(amount) {
  var WIDTH = $(sandbox).width();
  var HEIGHT = $(sandbox).height();

  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    addLiving(Math.round(Math.random() * 9999999), Math.round(Math.random() * WIDTH), Math.round(Math.random() * HEIGHT), 15);
  }
}

function addLiving(ID, LEFT, TOP, FOOD) {
  $(sandbox).append('<div id="id' + ID + '" class="livingBeing" style="position:absolute;top:' + TOP + 'px;left:' + LEFT + 'px;background-color:#000;width:1px;height:1px" food="' + FOOD + '"></div>');
}

function step() {
  $(".livingBeing").each(function() {
    move(this);
    eat(this);
    split(this);
    if (Math.round(parseInt($(this).attr("food"), 10)) > 0) {
      $(this).attr("food", Math.round(parseInt($(this).attr("food"), 10) - 1));
    } else {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
}

function move(living) {
  var way = Math.round(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  console.log(way);
  if (way === 1) {
    $(living).css({
      'top': "+=1px"
    });
  }
  if (way === 2) {
    $(living).css({
      'top': "-=1px"
    });
  }
  if (way === 3) {
    $(living).css({
      'left': "-=1px"
    });
  }
  if (way === 4) {
    $(living).css({
      'left': "+=1px"
    });
  }

  if ($(living).position().top > $(sandbox).height()) {
    $(living).css({
      'top': "-=1px"
    });
  }
  if ($(living).position().top < $(sandbox).height()) {
    $(living).css({
      'top': "+=1px"
    });
  }
  if ($(living).position().left > $(sandbox).height()) {
    $(living).css({
      'left': "-=1px"
    });
  }
  if ($(living).position().left < $(sandbox).height()) {
    $(living).css({
      'left': "+=1px"
    });
  }
}

function eat(living) {
  //if livingBeing1 is now at the same spot as livingbeing2 then livingBeing2 dies and
  //livingBeing1 gets livingBeing2's food
  $(".livingBeing").each(function() {
    if ($(this).position().top === $(living).position().top && $(this).position().left === $(living).position().left && $(this).id !== $(living).id) {
      $(living).attr("food", parseInt($(living).attr("food"), 10) + parseInt($(this).attr("food"), 10));
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
}

function split(living) {
  //if food greater than/equal (Math.random()*10)+2; then split
  if (parseInt($(living).attr("food"), 10) >= (Math.random() * 20) + 10) {
    addLiving(Math.round(Math.random() * 9999999), $(living).position().left + 1, $(living).position().top + 1, Math.floor(parseInt($(living).attr("food"), 10) / 2));
    $(living).attr("food", Math.floor(parseInt($(living).attr("food"), 10) / 2));
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <title>testing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've created 100 amount with 500 width & height and looks random. Cool project indeed.

Comment: @stig-js Do you think it's cool? thanks, but it is still shitty in the sense I'm using `.each` to detect which bacterium is in the same spot as another, and it's so heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1.** This is not right:

```
Math.round(Math.random() * 3) + 1
```

`Math.random() * 3` gives you a random number between 0 and 3. That's 4 different numbers but their distribution is not equal.

Rounding and adding 1 will make:

- if 0..0.5 => 1 (interval size: 0.5 => 16.66% chance) => up
- if 0.5..1.5 => 2 (interval size: 1 => 33.33% chance) => down
- if 1.5..2.5 => 3 (interval size: 1 => 33.33% chance) => left
- if 2.5..3 => 4 (interval size: 0.5 => 16.66% chance) => right

So that should make the bacteria tend to go down and left.

This will make a more equal distribution:

```
Math.trunc(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
```

**Problem 2.**

```
if ($(living).position().top < $(sandbox).height()) {
  $(living).css({
    'top': "+=1px"
  });
}
```

This means that if the top is within the bounds than make it go down. I think you wanted `.top < 0`. Same for `.left < $(sandbox).height()`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your answer, I, You nailed it +1. "I think you wanted `.top < 0`" -  Oh, I'm a dumbass, I forgot about that damn it

Answer (score 0):

To get the Javascript Math.Random to be truly random you need to use Math.Floor and add a multiplier.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
```

Explanation here - http://blog.ginchen.de/en/2010/10/09/javascripts-math-random-wenn-zufall-keiner-ist/